# How do I reliably capture the output of `ls` in this script?

Tags: ls, variable, stdout

The following script, `play_movie.sh` is meant to automatically select a movie if there is only one in the current directory and play it with `ffplay`. Otherwise it is meant to display a selection of films to the user and take input from them (the film to be played).

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

output_a=$(ls -R *.[aA][vV][iI] 2>/dev/null)
output_m=$(ls -R *.[mM][kKpP][vV4]] 2>/dev/null)
output_v=$(ls -R *.[vV][oO][bB]] 2>/dev/null)
all_exts="${output_a}${output_m}${output_v}"
ln_cnt=$(echo "${all_exts}" | wc -l)

if [[ "$ln_cnt" -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo -e "Playing: ${all_exts}\n"
  ffplay -hide_banner -infbuf -fs -sn -ast a:0 "${all_exts}"
elif [[ "$ln_cnt" -gt 1 ]]; then
  printf "Select a file out of the list below"
  ls -R *.[aA][vV][iI] 2>/dev/null 
  ls -R *.[mM][kKpP][vV4] 2>/dev/null 
  ls -R *.[vV][oO][bB] 2>/dev/null
  read line; ffplay -hide_banner -infbuf -fs -sn -ast a:0 "$line"
fi
```

The problem that I have with this script:

1. The script executes the first branch of `if` statement even if there are many movies in the current directory. Then I get `No such file or directory`.
2. If there is only one film to be played I get `No such file or directory`.

I had trouble relying on the output of `ls` in the past. Is it doable to fix this script without the need of using `find`?

Comment: You don't. `ls` doesn't work like that and you can't really parse the output of `ls` reliable. Use `find ... -print0` and arrays (`readarray -td ''` in bash) or zsh and its recursive globs with qualifiers instead

Comment: If you think you need to parse the output of `ls`, chances are you are approaching the problem incorrectly. `find` is usually what you want instead, possibly plus some post-processing of the file names or some calls to `stat` to get the data you want.

Comment: Why are you using the `-R` option? That's for recursing into subdirectories.

Comment: @Barmar `-R` is not necessary. Sometimes I have directories of many seasons of a TV series - in that case I find that useful.

Comment: When debugging, shell flag `-x` is your friend! Also using shell arrays (in BASH) is probably more reliable (like `array=($(ls -R | grep 'your pattern'))`; `${#array[*]}` is the number of items).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming the “if there is only one in the current directory” part is correct (*i.e.* you only care about files in the current directory), you can avoid using `ls`, let alone `find`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash -

shopt -s nullglob
set -- *.[aA][vV][iI] *.[mM][kKpP][vV4] *.[vV][oO][bB]

if [[ "$#" -eq 1 ]]; then
  printf>&2 "Playing: %s\n\n" "$@"
  ffplay -hide_banner -infbuf -fs -sn -ast a:0 -- "$@"
elif [[ "$#" -gt 1 ]]; then
  printf>&2 "Select a file out of the list below:\n"
  printf>&2 "%s\n" "$@"
  IFS= read -r line &&
    ffplay -hide_banner -infbuf -fs -sn -ast a:0 -- "$line"
fi
```

This sets `nullglob` so that globs with no matches are removed, then sets the parameters to all matching files.

As illustrated in [Stéphane Chazelas’ answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/754650/86440), you can use `select` to improve the user experience (`select` uses the positional parameters by default, which fits in nicely with the use of `set` above):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash -

shopt -s nullglob
set -- *.[aA][vV][iI] *.[mM][kKpP][vV4] *.[vV][oO][bB]

if [[ "$#" -eq 1 ]]; then
  printf>&2 "Playing: %s\n\n" "$@"
  ffplay -hide_banner -infbuf -fs -sn -ast a:0 -- "$@"
elif [[ "$#" -gt 1 ]]; then
  select video; do
    ffplay -hide_banner -infbuf -fs -sn -ast a:0 -- "$video"
    exit
  done
fi
```

Comment: Would you decode `set -- *.[aA][vV][iI] *.[mM][kKpP][vV4] *.[vV][oO][bB]` for me? What does `--` mean? The line seems to assign the output of `ls *.[aA][vV][iI] *.[mM][kKpP][vV4] *.[vV][oO][bB]` to `$@`

Comment: [`set` can do many things](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html); one of those is to set the [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html). `set -- foo` will set the positional parameters to the single string “foo”; the `--` is used to indicate the start of the arguments for the positional parameters (and allows an empty set of arguments to be distinguished from the no-argument `set` invocation).

Comment: With `set -- *.[aA][vV][iI] *.[mM][kKpP][vV4] *.[vV][oO][bB]`, the shell expands the globs; since `nullglob` is enabled, globs with no matches are removed, and globs with matches are replaced with those matches. Then `set --` sets the positional parameters to the files that were found (if any). `"$@"` expands to all the positional parameters, properly quoted. `$#` expands to the number of positional parameters, which corresponds to the number of files found.

Answer (score 12):

You can't use `ls` like that. Those `*.[aA][vV][iI]` are expanded by the shell, not `ls`, the `-R` for `ls` is for it to `R`ecursively list the contents of directories, for which you need to pass it the path of directories, not files, and even then, it would output the list of files (any non-hidden files) in those directories without their directory components, so `ffmpeg` could not find them.

Also, unless you use the `--zero` option of very recent versions of the GNU implementation of `ls`, the output of `ls` is simply not post-processable reliably.

Here to find files with that list of extensions anywhere in the current working directory and below, you'd use `find`. To store a list of files (or of anything for that matters), you use an array variable, not a string/scalar variable.

Using `zsh` instead of `bash` here would make it a lot easier as zsh has (properly working) recursive globbing and glob qualifiers which mean you can also restrict the list of files to those of type *regular*. Globs also skip hidden files by default (like `ls` but not `find` where you need to do that skipping by hand):

```
#! /usr/bin/zsh -
set -o extendedglob
videos=( **/*.(#i)(avi|mkv|mp4|vob)(N-.) )

play() {
  print -ru2 Playing $argv
  ffplay -hide_banner -infbuf -fs -sn -ast a:0 -- $argv
}

case $#videos in
  (0) print -u2 No video found; exit 1;;
  (1) play $videos;;
  (*) print -u2 Select a video:
      select video in $videos; do
        play $video || exit
        break
      done;;
esac
```

With `bash` (the GNU shell) + GNU `find`, you could do something approaching with:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash -
readarray -td '' videos < <(
  LC_ALL=C find . \
    -regextype posix-extended \
    -name '.?*' -prune -o \
      -iregex '.*\.(avi|mkv|mp4|vob)' \
      -xtype f \
      -printf '%P\0' |
    sort -z
)

shopt -u xpg_echo
play() {
  echo>&2 -E Playing "$@"
  ffplay -hide_banner -infbuf -fs -sn -ast a:0 -- "$@"
}

case ${#videos[@]} in
  (0) echo>&2 No video found; exit 1;;
  (1) play "${videos[@]}";;
  (*) echo>&2 Select a video:
      select video in "${videos[@]}"; do
        play "$video" || exit
        break
      done;;
esac
```

Some other notes:

- Your `echo -e` would break for filenames that contain `\` characters. Here you do *not* want the `e`scape sequences to be expanded, hence the `-E` for `echo` or `-r` for `print`. If you want it to print an extra newline, add it to the last argument of `echo` literally or with `$'\n'`. Also note that `bash`'s `echo` only accepts options if either the `posix` or `xpg_echo` is unset (and they are set by default on some systems and/or some environments). Generally, using `echo` is best avoided, I still use it here for its ability to easily print its arguments joined with spaces (which is more cumbersome to do with `printf`, and bash only has `print` as a loadable plugin whose few systems have included by default when they have bash at all) and on the ground that we know the shell is `bash`, so the `play` function could be used to play more than one video at a time.
- Prompts and user messages should generally go to stderr (fd 2). That's where `select`'s output goes for instance.
- [The syntax to read a line is `IFS= read -r line`](/q/209123), not `read line`. But in any case, file paths don't have to be made of a single line, as the newline character is as valid as any in a file name.
- note that your `*.[mM][kKpP][vV4]` would also match on `files.mv4` (not *`m4v`*).